# Angular2 expression + jquery

Tags: angular

I have the following expression, which works:

```
<div class="circle" data-value="0.8">%</div>
```

when i'm trying to bind an attribute to it:

```
[data-value]="result/100"
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'data-value' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Why and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `<div class="circle" [data-value]="result/100">%</div>` to

```
<div class="circle" [attr.data-value]="result/100">%</div>
```

or

```
<div class="circle" attr.data-value="{{result/100}}">%<div>
```

Comment: Seems the last option doesn't work. It should be  `attr.data-value="{{result/100}}"`